# Skip comments in python text file and insert column headings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a large dataset, in which I have the data in the following format (this is not the true data),

```
#relation 'train'
#attri 'x' real
#attri 'y' integer
#attri 'z' binary (0/1)
#attri 'a' real
#attri 'b' integer
#attri 'class' binary(good/bad)
#data
1.2, 5, 0, 2.3, 4, good
1.3, 6, 1, 1.8, 5, bad
1.6, 7, 0, 1.9, 6, good
2.1, 8, 1, 2.1, 8, good
```

I tried with pandas (although I would like to use python alone).
[image]

I want 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'class' as the heading of the columns. Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one potential solution:

1) Read the `DataFrame` in ignoring comments, with no header.

2) Read the file in again including comments, but limiting the row number to just the number of columns of `df` + 1.

3) Use a regex pattern to extract the header name.

4) Assign the headers to the column names of your original `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=',', comment='#', header=None)

s = pd.read_csv('test.txt', nrows=len(df.columns)+1, names=['headers'])
columns = s.headers.str.extract(r'^#attri \'(.+)\'').dropna().values.flatten()

df.columns = columns
```

Answer (score 1):

First we can extract the column names from the `.txt` file like following:

```
import re

columns = []

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip()
        if l.startswith('#attri'):
            columns.append(re.findall(r"'(.{1})'", l))

columns = [item for sublist in columns for item in sublist]
```

Apparently your csv has no header, so you have to explicitly use the `headers` argument in [`pd.read_csv`](http://s.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) like following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', comment='#', header=None)

# Now we can set the column names correctly
df.columns = columns
```

**2nd option** use `names` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', 
                 comment='#', 
                 header=None,
                 names=columns)
```

**Test**

```
import re

columns = []

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip()
        if l.startswith('#attri'):
            columns.append(re.findall(r"'(.{1})'", l))

columns = [item for sublist in columns for item in sublist]

print(columns)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']

# Now we have the column names, we can read the csv
from io import StringIO

a = StringIO('''
1.2, 5, 0, 2.3, 4, good
1.3, 6, 1, 1.8, 5, bad
1.6, 7, 0, 1.9, 6, good
2.1, 8, 1, 2.1, 8, good
''')

df = pd.read_csv(a, 
                 comment='#', 
                 header=None,
                 names=columns)

print(df)
     x  y    z  a      b
1.2  5  0  2.3  4   good
1.3  6  1  1.8  5    bad
1.6  7  0  1.9  6   good
2.1  8  1  2.1  8   good
```

Comment: Can we automate this column name task? Because I have more than 200 columns and corresponding names.

Comment: Are the column names stored somewhere? Apparently they are not in `test.txt` am I right?

Comment: The data here I have mentioned is a small dataset (dummy). But my actual data contains more than 200 columns and names as mentioned in the above post. It is of course in the same text file.

Comment: Thanks Erfan!! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the columns of a pandas dataframe you can use

```
df.columns = [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: This is incorrect, first row is been imported as header, so this will remove the first row.